# How to sort a Dataframe by the ocurrences in a column in Python (pandas)

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to create a dataframe  from my data (scores between chemicals and proteins) with pandas in python.

I want my dataframe to first display the proteins that have the most occurences, so I previously sorted my data. But when I make the dataframe it does not get the expected result.

Here's a sample of my data :

```
chemicals   prots   scores
CID000000006    10116.ENSRNOP00000003921    196
CID000000051    10116.ENSRNOP00000003921    246
CID000000085    10116.ENSRNOP00000003921    196
CID000000119    10116.ENSRNOP00000003921    247
CID000000134    10116.ENSRNOP00000008952    159
CID000000135    10116.ENSRNOP00000008952    157
CID000000174    10116.ENSRNOP00000008952    439
CID000000175    10116.ENSRNOP00000001021    858
CID000000177    10116.ENSRNOP00000004027    760
```

As you can see "10116.ENSRNOP00000003921" is the protein with the most occurences in my data.

So i'd like to get something like :

```
             10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     10116.ENSRNOP00000008952  
CID000000006   196                 
CID000000051   246 
CID000000085   196 
CID000000119   247 
CID000000134                                  159   
CID000000135                                  157   
CID000000174                                  439
```

And Here's my code :

```
import pandas as pd

df_rat= pd.read_csv("dt_matrix_rat.csv",sep="\t", header=True)
df_rat.columns = ['chemicals','proteins','scores']
df_rat1 = df_rat.pivot(index='chemicals', columns='proteins', values='scores')

df_rat1.to_csv("rat_matrix.csv", sep='\t', index=True  )
```

Comment: You can use `collections.Counter.most_common()` to get the number of occurences, but it seems you already have those... The rest kind of looks like a pivot table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table

Comment: The data are already sorted by proteins occurences, it's just that the matrice i get  does not display the in the result in the right order

Comment: @ELWalou, do you mean wrong order of columns or of rows?

Comment: i don't get your question so let me clarify it. I think instead of sorting, i think you want to create a new dataframe where the columns represents the proteins and are sorted in descending order of occurences. Am I correct?

Comment: @John ,Titus exactly , sorry if it was not clear. I'll edit my post and try to make it more understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html) of [`notnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.notnull.html) of [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and get index to `cols`. Lasy use `subset`:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='chemicals', columns='proteins', values='scores')

cols = df1.notnull().sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False).index
print cols
Index([u'10116.ENSRNOP00000003921', u'10116.ENSRNOP00000008952',
       u'10116.ENSRNOP00000004027', u'10116.ENSRNOP00000001021'],
      dtype='object', name=u'proteins')

print df1[cols]
proteins      10116.ENSRNOP00000003921  10116.ENSRNOP00000008952  \
chemicals                                                          
CID000000006                     196.0                       NaN   
CID000000051                     246.0                       NaN   
CID000000085                     196.0                       NaN   
CID000000119                     247.0                       NaN   
CID000000134                       NaN                     159.0   
CID000000135                       NaN                     157.0   
CID000000174                       NaN                     439.0   
CID000000175                       NaN                       NaN   
CID000000177                       NaN                       NaN   

proteins      10116.ENSRNOP00000004027  10116.ENSRNOP00000001021  
chemicals                                                         
CID000000006                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000051                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000085                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000119                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000134                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000135                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000174                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000175                       NaN                     858.0  
CID000000177                     760.0                       NaN
```

Or [`reindex_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_axis.html):

```
print df1.reindex_axis(cols, axis=1)
proteins      10116.ENSRNOP00000003921  10116.ENSRNOP00000008952  \
chemicals                                                          
CID000000006                     196.0                       NaN   
CID000000051                     246.0                       NaN   
CID000000085                     196.0                       NaN   
CID000000119                     247.0                       NaN   
CID000000134                       NaN                     159.0   
CID000000135                       NaN                     157.0   
CID000000174                       NaN                     439.0   
CID000000175                       NaN                       NaN   
CID000000177                       NaN                       NaN   

proteins      10116.ENSRNOP00000004027  10116.ENSRNOP00000001021  
chemicals                                                         
CID000000006                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000051                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000085                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000119                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000134                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000135                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000174                       NaN                       NaN  
CID000000175                       NaN                     858.0  
CID000000177                     760.0                       NaN
```

Comment: Isn't something missing in the "sort_values()" in the second line of your code ?
I get :  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'index'

Comment: I use version pandas 0.18.0. I think problem is if use older version.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use @jezrael's solution or do it this way (which is pretty similar):

```
In [136]: df
Out[136]:
      chemicals                     prots  scores
0  CID000000006  10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     196
1  CID000000051  10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     246
2  CID000000085  10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     196
3  CID000000119  10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     247
4  CID000000134  10116.ENSRNOP00000008952     159
5  CID000000135  10116.ENSRNOP00000008952     157
6  CID000000174  10116.ENSRNOP00000008952     439
7  CID000000175  10116.ENSRNOP00000001021     858
8  CID000000177  10116.ENSRNOP00000004027     760
```

Prepare right order

```
In [169]: df.groupby('prots').sum().sort('scores', ascending=False)
Out[169]:
                          scores
prots
10116.ENSRNOP00000003921     885
10116.ENSRNOP00000001021     858
10116.ENSRNOP00000004027     760
10116.ENSRNOP00000008952     755
```

Prepare list of sorted columns (for old versions of pandas) use `.sort()` instead of `.sort_values()`:

```
In [170]: cols = df.groupby('prots').sum().sort_values(by='scores', ascending=False).index

In [171]: cols
Out[171]:
Index(['10116.ENSRNOP00000003921', '10116.ENSRNOP00000001021',
       '10116.ENSRNOP00000004027', '10116.ENSRNOP00000008952'],
      dtype='object', name='prots')
```

Pivot and set your columns in the right order:

```
In [175]: df_rat1 = df.pivot(index='chemicals', columns='prots', values='scores').fillna('')

In [176]: df_rat1 = df_rat1[cols]

In [177]: df_rat1
Out[177]:
prots        10116.ENSRNOP00000003921 10116.ENSRNOP00000001021 10116.ENSRNOP00000004027 10116.ENSRNOP00000008952
chemicals
CID000000006                      196
CID000000051                      246
CID000000085                      196
CID000000119                      247
CID000000134                                                                                                 159
CID000000135                                                                                                 157
CID000000174                                                                                                 439
CID000000175                                               858
CID000000177                                                                        760
```

Comment: the line 170 always get me the "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'" error message

Comment: @ELWalou, try using `sort` instead of `sort_values`. you might be using an older version of pandas.

Comment: @ELWalou, what pandas version do you have?

Comment: @MaxU '0.14.1' 
(I'm not root)

Comment: @ELWalou, then use `.sort()` instead of `.sort_values()` as John said